# CSS counter fails to increment inside <ul>

Tags: css, html, counter

This question concerns using the CSS *counter* feature in HTML5 inside a list (e.g. **<ul>**).

Given this in the .css file:

```
body {
counter-reset:figCounter;
counter-reset:figRefCounter;
counter-increment: figRefCounter;   
}
.caption {
  counter-increment: figCounter; 
}

.figNumber:before {
    content: "Figure";
}

.figNumber:after {
    content: counter(figCounter);
}
```

The example below works correctly, that is, the divs generate "Figure 1" and "Figure 2" respectively:

```
<div class="caption">
 <p><span class="figNumber">&nbsp;</span>:&nbsp;First Caption</p>
</div>
<div class="caption">
  <p><span class="figNumber">&nbsp;</span>:&nbsp;Second Caption</p>
</div>
```

On the other hand, the counter does not increment -- both divs end up generating "Figure 1" -- if I put the first div inside a list, like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="caption">
      <p><span class="figNumber">&nbsp;</span>:&nbsp;First Caption</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="caption">
  <p><span class="figNumber">&nbsp;</span>:&nbsp;Second Caption</p>
</div>
```

How can I get the counter to increment inside a list, so that the second div generates "Figure 2" like it does without the list?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me (on Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m, Firefox 25.0.1, and IE11) at http://jsfiddle.net/z9ngu/. It produces `1: First Caption` as a list item, then `2: Second Caption` below that as not a list item.

Comment: Also worked fine for me on Safari 5.1.7 for Win7.

Answer (score 3):

When using multiple `Counter-reset`s, you should define them in one line:

```
body {
    counter-reset:figCounter, figRefCounter;
    counter-increment: figRefCounter;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BR23F/)

*Note it is not neccesary to increase the counter at the body, it will be one by default for the first time*

Comment: +1. It seems you were the only one who actually solved the problem.

Comment: @BrianGraham If you would notice, the question was changed. The original question was a little different.

Comment: @abhitalks thanks for noticing. But even with the new 'layout' it works [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BR23F/)

Comment: @nkmol: Yes absolutely. Because you rectified the counter-reset syntax. There is no problem with your answer. The earlier question didn't have multiple counters at all! The Op changed the question during his comments with me! Anyways, you did answer correctly and I do appreciate that! Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, abhitalks is correct about me changing the question.  And BrianGraham's rectified counter-reset syntax solved my problem!  So thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code as is working just fine.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/SrewW**

Moreover, if you make the `list-style-type` to `none`, then it looks seamless:

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/SrewW/1/**

Result in both cases:

> 1 : First Caption
>
> 2 : Second Caption

**And**,

If you remove the trailing comma after `.figNumber:before`, then the result is like this:

> Figure 1 : First Caption
>
> Figure 2 : Second Caption

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/SrewW/2/**

**Update:** (*Moving the comments here for easy ref*)

You do not actually need to put colons and spaces in your html markup. Also, you do not need counter-increment on `caption`. You can do that on your `fignumber` span itself.

Please understand the counters. This link will help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

You can have many counters. You can reset them anywhere, but safe would be to reset in body. But you increment those on an element where you want to show the counter.

Please see this fiddle for reference: **http://jsfiddle.net/m6u6a/4/**

For example:

```
body {
    counter-reset: figCounter 10 figRefCounter 0;
}

.figNumber:before {
    counter-increment: figCounter 2; 
    content: "Figure " counter(figCounter) ": ";
}
```

Here, `figCounter` is initialized to 10 and `figRefCounter` is initialized to 0 in body. However, on the span with class `figNumber`, the `figCounter is incremented to 2 and displayed with supporting text in the`:before` pseudo-class.

The result:

> Figure 12: First Caption
>
> Figure 14: Second Caption

Hope that makes it clear to you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I caught that comma.  The code with the <ul> does *not* work properly for me.  Are you saying it does work for you?

Comment: It is working perfectly with Chrome v31 here on my comp. Which browser are you testing against?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct for this case.  I had left the "body" part out of the CSS file, which is why it didn't work for me.  However, I do have a more complex case where adding <ul> seems to break the counter.  I'll try to whittle that case down a bit and put something up here.

Comment: Okay, so with two lines added to the body selector in the CSS (see edited version of my original post) it works properly without the <ul> but not with it.  See http://jsfiddle.net/m6u6a/

Comment: (1) Your syntax is incorrect. The correct syntax is: `counter-reset: counter1 counter2;` or `counter-reset: counter1 0 counter2 0;` (2) You shouldn't be incrementing a counter on body. You would increment a counter on the element you want the counter on. See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6u6a/2/

Comment: In fact please see this updated fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/m6u6a/4/. It would help you understand better. You don't need those ":" and `&nbsp;` in your html. Also, no need to use `caption` for increment.

Comment: @user1147171 Were you able to get this going? I updated the answer by moving these comments there.